# XML Parser add values to self closing tag

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to build an XML as follows

```
<set author="user" id="1">
   <comment>"sample comment"</comment>
   <sqlFile path="path/sample.sql" />
</set>
```

My code:

```
def baseLog=new XmlParser().parse("./template.xml") // base template file to which i want to add nodes
newNode = new Node(baseLog, 'set', [author:'user', id: '1'])
newNode.appendNode(new QName("comment"),[:],"test comment")
newNode.appendNode(new QName("sqlFile"))
```

The above works just fine, i want to find a way to add `path="path/sample.sql"` to `<sqlFile/>` self closing tag like `<sqlFile path="path/sample.sql" />`

Comment: Have you tried `new QName("sqlFile", [path: "path/sample.sql"])`?

Comment: it worked thanks !

i had to give it like  - `newNode.appendNode("sqlFile", [path:"./${projectDir}/${operation}/${line}"])`